# error code not available in axios response (react frontend) when 503 service maintenance

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, axios

When maintenance mode of heroku turned on, it creates a 503 error in the frontend. The problem is there aren't any distinguishable property in the error response which only says

```
Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

type of it still and object but there arent any items in it.

This is a react-app run on a Django server and hosted on Heroku.

```
axios.get('myAPI').then(res => {
...
})
.catch(e => console.log(e)
```

is there any way to distinguish 503 on the front-end?

Comment: can you check `e.response.status` in `catch` block that might help.

Comment: I did it, that is the problem actually there aren't any item in the e object

Comment: Are you sure heroku returns a Network error in this case? It looks like a client side network error.

Comment: Dogan, Yes I can still see the response on the network tab and its not a OPTIONS request neither, it returns with a 503 from a GET request. but its not available on the error object

Comment: @NaimMustafa if you are getting proper GET request can you check this [thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1143#issuecomment-340331822) of issues on axios github.

Comment: @NarkhedeTushar, this is giving ```No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.``` enabling cors might be the solution